# start mongos(mongodb 4.4 sharding router) using systemd service

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb 4.4 on centos 8 using official RPM repo.

I can start & use mongos from command line just fine:
`mongos --config /etc/mongos.conf`

However, if I try to start mongos as systemd service, it give the error `mongos.service: Failed with result 'timeout'`. During the start process, I can connect to mongos and it is working until the start script error out.

the content of /etc/mongos.conf

```
sharding:
  configDB: rs_cfg/web05:27017

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

The content of `/etc/systemd/system/mongos.service`.  Basically I took `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` and make minor modifications to produce `mongos.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongos.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongos $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid
Type=forking
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> journalctl -xe

```
systemd[1]: mongos.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
systemd[1]: mongos.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Checked all dir permissions, it just does not create the pid file `/var/run/mongodb/mongos.pid`.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `Type=forking` but mongos is not configured to fork. You should reset this to its default, `Type=simple`. Alternatively you can add `--fork` to the mongos command line, but you will also need to specify `--pidfile`. The PID file is not required with `Type=simple`. Since you're using systemd it's best to just not fork and let systemd handle managing the process.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me to the right direction.  I copied the systemd script from mongod but did not config mongos to have the same fork/pid setting as mongod.  It is working now.